# How to sort activerecord query by specific prority

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am using rails 3 and postrges.

I would like order by a specific priority.

Something like:

```
Assignment.order(priority: ['best', 'good', 'bad'])
```

and this will return all activerecords first with 'best', then 'good', then 'bad'

I cannot seem to find anything like this. I do not need an array, it has to be activerecords.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Order can be any SQL code. You can use a `CASE` statement to map your values to values that naturally sort in the correct order.

```
Assignment.order("
    CASE
      WHEN priority = 'best' THEN '1'
      WHEN priority = 'good' THEN '2'
      WHEN priority = 'bad' THEN '3'
    END")
```

Even better, you could move this logic to the model so that it's easier to call from controllers:

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def self.priority_order
    order("
        CASE
          WHEN priority = 'best' THEN '1'
          WHEN priority = 'good' THEN '2'
          WHEN priority = 'bad' THEN '3'
        END")
  end
end
```

Then you can just call `Assignment.priority_order` to get your sorted records.

If this column is sortable in the view, add a parameter to the method for direction:

```
def self.priority_order(direction = "ASC")
  # Prevent injection by making sure the direction is either ASC or DESC
  direction = "ASC" unless direction.upcase.match(/\ADESC\Z/)
  order("
      CASE
        WHEN priority = 'best' THEN '1'
        WHEN priority = 'good' THEN '2'
        WHEN priority = 'bad' THEN '3'
      END #{direction}")
end
```

Then, you would call `Assignment.priority_order(params[:direction])` to pass in the sorting from the controller.

Answer (score 10):

In newer versions of Rails you will get an `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeReference (Query method called with non-attribute argument(s)` error if you pass raw SQL to `.order()`.

You need to wrap your SQL query with `Arel.sql()`. You can also use ruby's [Here Doucment](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Here+Documents) syntax, to write multi line SQL statements, and [squish](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-squish) to make it more readable in the console.

So the whole thing becomes:

```
Assignment.order(
  Arel.sql(<<-SQL.squish
    CASE
      WHEN priority = 'best' THEN '1'
      WHEN priority = 'good' THEN '2'
      WHEN priority = 'bad' THEN '3'
    END
  SQL
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The ActiveRecord Query method `in_order_of` has been introduced in Rails 7.

See https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-in_order_of

> Allows to specify an order by a specific set of values.

```rb
User.in_order_of(:id, [1, 5, 3])
# SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
#   WHERE "users"."id" IN (1, 5, 3)
#   ORDER BY CASE
#     WHEN "users"."id" = 1 THEN 1
#     WHEN "users"."id" = 5 THEN 2
#     WHEN "users"."id" = 3 THEN 3
#   END ASC
```